# jQuery selection via class generating error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to get some divs that all have the same class via the following jquery code:

```
var divs = $('.divClass');
```

And then loop through and get each height and left css property of the each div.  I have tried 2 methods, both unsuccesfully.

First:

```
divs.each( function(d) {
     var height = d.height();
     // also tried:
     var height2 = d.css("height");
});
```

Second:

```
var divArray = divs.toArray();
for (var i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++) {
    var height = divArray[i].height();
}
```

Both these throw the error:  "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function.".  What is really strange is `divs.first().height()` returns the correct value.  Also, the array has the correct number of members.  Is there something wrong I am doing with either iteration scheme? This is incredibly annoying.  Today I found out why everyone complains about JS.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each()` has two arguments, index and the DOM element (which would also be the value of `this`)

```
divs.each( function(index, element) {
     var height = $(element).height();
});
```

Comment: I'll try that.. any idea why the for loop doesn't work though?

Comment: `divArray[i]` is the native DOM element, not a jQuery object

Comment: Damn.. feel like an idiot.  The 2nd answer on this question should be downvoted on account of me wasting half my afternoon on it!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554348/loading-all-objects-with-class-into-an-array-using-jquery  Will always, always look at the documentation first in the future.

Comment: Sure, no problem! We've all made mistakes like that, I still sometimes get the arguments mixed up, especielly on each() and map(), as the arguments are in opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong because `d` will not be a DOM element but the zero-based index of the current element in the matched set.

Instead of this, within the `.each` callback refer to the current element with `$(this)`:

```
divs.each(function() {
   var height = $(this).height();
});
```

You can also get the current element from the *second* (not first) argument passed to the callback, but there's no need to.